# What is Class any in kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, any

So I have to make a presentation about class any in Kotlin, I'm a complete beginner so I don't know much, if anybody can link to class any docs or explain in few words what it does or how it works.

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any` is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. What this means is that every* value in Kotlin is implicitly an `Any`.

In the same way that every `List<T>` is also a `Collection<T>` and every `Integer` and `Double` is also a `Number`, every* single value in Kotlin is also an `Any`.

If a method accepts an `Any` parameter, it means it accepts, well, literally any* type of value, be it `String`, `Integer`, `Array<Animal>`, `List<Foo>` `MyCoolClass` or anything else.

*) Aside from `null`. `Any` covers all non-`null` values. Similarly, `Any?` means "`Any`, but this time also including `null`".

If you're familiar with Java, `Any` is Kotlin's counterpart to Java's `Object` which is the root of every type of value (aside from primitives).